# Does netsnmp 5.7.* support SHA2?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, sha2

Does netsnmp 5.7.* support SHA2 ? 
Can we use openSSL library and make use of strong algorithms in netSNMP?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: SNMP protocol itself only defined MD5 and SHA-1. Using SHA-2 with SNMP (any implementation) would be beyond the standard, and is determined merely by the vendor. Contact the developers, check their release notes and perform your own code review and whatever else. Just don't post such questions here, as that's your home work, and out of scope here.

Comment: @LexLi https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7860

Comment: Net-SNMP 5.8 added support for HMAC-SHA2. 5.7 would likely not work without extensive changes.